# What is SQL's Keyword order? (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, syntax

Depending on where you put SELECT, FROM, WHERE, etc, I have run into syntax errors. What is the proper order to write queries and code? An example below:

```
//No error
SELECT count(*)
FROM us_counties_pop_est_2019
WHERE births_2019 - deaths_2019 <=0;
```

vs

```
//Syntax error
SELECT count(*) 
WHERE births_2019 - deaths_2019 <=0
FROM us_counties_pop_est_2019;
```

Comment: See here [SQL syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql.html) in particular [Queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *main clauses* of a `SELECT` statement in PostgreSQL are written in the following order:

- `[WITH]`
- `SELECT`
- `FROM`
- `JOIN`
- `WHERE`
- `GROUP BY`
- `HAVING`
- `WINDOW`
- `ORDER BY`
- `OFFSET`
- `LIMIT`

If the query includes CTEs, then the `WITH` clause comes before the other ones.

Comment: you seem really knowledgeable on sql and postgress. I'm a student, any recommendations on consolidated resources for my understanding of both SQL language || Database design & functionality ?

Comment: @MarkThomas PostgreSQL is one of the most standard database engines in the market, and it's also free. If you want to learn SQL I would recommend learning using PosgreSQL and focus on constraints. For database design, you probably need to start with theory, and focus on normalization (1NF, 2NF, 3NF). Finally, you can tackle database design, properly; there are a number of web sites that teach that.